# cannot get the favorite movies from tmdb with validated session ID?

Tags: api, themoviedb-api

I can get the account details via session ID but cannot get the favorite movies with this same session ID. Anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have a valid `session_id` for a user, all you need to do is call the users `/movie/favorite` method. Here's an example:

```
https://api.themoviedb.org/3/account/{ID}/favorite/movies?api_key={API_KEY}&session_id={SESSION_ID}
```

Note the `{ID}`, `{API_KEY}` and `{SESSION_ID}` vars that need to be changed.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If that document is real paper, trust me I will  tear it up. I mean thank you so much, I missed the restful idea and thought the ID is the session ID.

Comment: The Id - is the Id of user. The User Id you can get with help of this request http://api.themoviedb.org/3/account?api_key=###&session_id=###